# jQuery Ui Tabs cannot handle onclick in loaded document

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jQuery Ui tabs like this

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.php">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.php">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">

    </div>
</div>
```

in the JavaScript I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#moreinfotabs" ).tabs();
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert("asdas");
    });
```

When content1.php for example is loaded, I want to handle click on the links in content1.php and to alert something but It's not happen. How to do that ?

PS: I wrote for a link, whatever I want to use with a.classname....

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically generated elements, events should be delegated, from one of static parents of the element, or document object.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    alert("asdas");
});
```

Please note that you haven't closed the document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#moreinfotabs" ).tabs();
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
        alert("asdas");
    });
}) // <--
```

Comment: + 1 and *just minor observation*: the OP forgot to close `});` in his/her `document.ready` `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit Thanks bro, yes, I forgot to mention that :)